# Is a browser obliged to use a DOM to render an HTML page?

Tags: html, dom, browser, render

I was reading the page about the Document Object Model on Wikipedia.

One sentence caught my interest; it says:

> A Web browser is not obliged to use DOM in order to render an HTML
>   document.

You can find the entire context on the page [right here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model#Applications).

I don't understand that is there any other alternative to render an HTML document? What exactly does this sentence mean?

Comment: It just means they don't have to follow the Document Object Model.  They could develop a new model all their own to structure the document but it would break a lot of other technologies out there that use the DOM such as javascript so you likely won't see any browsers straying too far from the DOM.

Comment: HTML is older that the DOM. The first browsers could not have used it.

Comment: Define DOM. The browser has no choice but to use objects to represent the elements on the page, which makes it a "document object model" (in the broader sense).

Comment: @Sime Vidas, not all programming languages use objects.

Comment: @zzzzBov What are the alternatives?

Comment: @Sime Vidas, you mean like assembly? Additionally, we're not talking about *a* DOM we're talking about **the** DOM, which is [outlined by the w3c](http://www.w3.org/DOM/)

Comment: @Alohci If the HTML is older than the DOM, then how did the browsers render the pages in those times? You could direct me to some resources, I'm not looking for a detailed answer in these comments.

Comment: @Hrishikesh - I'm not aware of any resources in this area, but there are a few clues. It's possible, in the days before CSS, to see HTML as a set of rendering instructions. e.g. `<p>` was originally a paragraph break, so it amounted to "Start a new line and leave some space above" in a visual medium or announcement of "New Paragraph" in an aural medium. Or start and end tags as "turn on feature X" and "turn off feature X" respectively, which is why things like `<b><i>my text</b></i>` work consistently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strictly speaking IE (at least < IE9) does not use a DOM to *render* an HTML document. It uses its own internal object model (which is not always a pure tree structure).

The DOM is an API, and IE maps the API methods and properties onto actions on its internal model. Since the DOM assumes a tree structure, the mapping is not always perfect, which accounts for a number of oddities when accessing the document via the DOM in IE.

Answer (score 3):

The primary job of a browser is to display HTML. Most browsers use a DOM; they parse the HTML, create a DOM structure from it (which can also be used in JavaScript) and render the page based on that DOM.

But if a browser chooses not to, it is free to do so. I wouldn't know why, and I certainly don't understand why this line is explicitly mentioned in the Wiki article..

Comment: So a browser *can* read HTML code and render the page as intended without following a DOM? Could you point me to some links where I could read more on things like this?